# why does python print not working after return?

Tags: python, recursion, return

Why does print statement not run after I return in recursion in Python?

```
arr=['zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine']
def numToWord(num):
    if num==0:
        return
    
    dig=num%10
    num=num//10
    #print(arr[dig],end=" ")
    return numToWord(num)
    print(arr[dig],end=" ")
    
numToWord(345)
```

Comment: Because return statement is end of the program in a block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
**A return is a value that a function returns to the calling script or function when it completes its task.
So here return takes as a termination of this function. That's why it will not jump to next line.**
```

Answer (score 0):

How return works is it ends the function and everything after it will not run. I would change your code to this:

```py
arr=['zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine']

def numToWord(num):
    if num == 0:
        return

    dig = num % 10
    num = num // 10
    return dig,num

dig,num=numToWord(345)
print(arr[dig],end=" ")
```

Comment: `dig,num = numToWord`? or `dig,num = numToWord(345)`

Comment: @Bibhav thanks that must of been a typo on my part